# Android DrawerToggle and Up Navigation

Tags: android, toggle, navigation-drawer, toolbar

I'm implementing a navigation drawer with a drawer toggle (with the hamburger-arrow animation) in the `Toolbar`. Till here everything works well. Now I would like to provide the up navigation with the back arrow, if the user switches the content to a lower level fragment. Here things went tricky. Currently my implementation looks like the following:

`ActivityMain.java`, when initializing the Toolbar with the Drawer etc.

```
setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);

    mActionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, mDrawerLayout, mToolbar, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {

        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {

            if(mDrawerFragment != null) {
                mDrawerFragment.onDrawerClose();
            }
        }

        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            mActionBarDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);

            if(mDrawerFragment != null) {
                mDrawerFragment.onDrawerOpen();
            }
        }
    };

    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mActionBarDrawerToggle);

    //Setze einen Custom-Clicklistener, der die Clicks auf den DrawerToggle handelt
    mToolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d("debug", "onclick");

            if(currentlyAttached instanceof GridViewFragment) {
                if(mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
                    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                }
                else {
                    mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                }
            }
            else {
                onBackPressed();
            }
        }
    });

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    mActionBarDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
    mActionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
```

I set a NavigationClicklistener for the Toolbar to catch the touchevent of the click. As one can see, I only want to open the navigation drawer if the user is on the root fragment (GridviewFragment). In the other cases I would like to provide the up navigation. The functionality itself (open/close drawer and go back) is working well, but the drawer toggle sometimes shows the wrong icons. An example:

1. Starting the app: I expect the hamburger icon (in my styles.xml I set the color to white). This is shown.
2. Switching content to a low level fragment: I expect the up navigation arrow (also in white). This is shown also, but in gray (why?).
3. Going back to the root fragment: I expect again the hamburger icon (in white). This is shown.
4. Switching again to a lower level fragment: I expect the up navigation arrow (in white). From now on the icon isn't changing anymore, I always see the hamburger icon in white.

And I have no clue why this is happening. Maybe anyone got an idea? That would be really great. I just post some additional code for a better understanding.

styles.xml, where I set the color to white

```
<style name="DrawerArrowStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
    <item name="spinBars">true</item>
    <item name="color">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

I have two methods that are called, when the fragments are changing and where I can do some stuff to influence the drawer toggle but I am not sure, what may be the best way here.

```
private void provideBackNavigation() {
    mActionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

private void provideMenuDrawerNavigation() {
    mActionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
}
```

Thanks for help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I have setup similar functionality in one of my own applications. I accomplished this by using the methods [`ActionBarDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle.html#setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(boolean)) and [`DrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.html#setDrawerLockMode(int, int)).

First, I created the following method:

```
public void setDrawerState(boolean isEnabled) {
    if (isEnabled) {
        mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED, GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED, GravityCompat.START);
    }
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}
```

This method allows you to lock the navigation drawer, making it impossible to open on the fragments you want to add up navigation. I placed this method in my `Activity` and call it in `onResume` of **all** of my fragments, so it is set accordingly for the fragments I wish to lock/unlock the drawer for.

Next, in my `Activity`, I also have the following setup:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(final MenuItem item) {
    if (mDrawerLayout.getDrawerLockMode(GravityCompat.START)
            != DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED
            && mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            onBackPressed();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

This allows the drawer to be opened if it is not locked, but if it is locked, then the up navigation functionality will take over.

Finally, my `onBackPressed` method is overridden as follows in my `Activity`:

```
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START))
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    else
        super.onBackPressed();
}
```

This will close the navigation drawer if it is open, and otherwise continue with default up navigation.

I believe that's all that I've set up, so let me know if it works for you.